# What are some of the Egyptian pyramid building theories?

Tags: egypt, ancient-egypt

What were some of the theories of how the Egyptian pyramids were built? I know about the one about placing logs under the stones to move them into place, but what are some other theories? Will there be back fire to those theories like if the logs were placed under the stone blocks they might sink into the sand?

Comment: Putting the big end at the bottom and placing less blocks on each layer as you go up were the major theoretical breakthroughs

Comment: Not the theories about aliens right? :D

Comment: Off course not :)

Comment: Per the [FAQ](http://history.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask), "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." This question falls into that category as too broad. There are many theories. If you have a specific, objective question, feel free to ask. However, as it is now, this question is too broad to be answered by one single answer.